# "I'm telling you..."

Tags: idiomatic-language

**Used to emphasize that what you are saying is true, and should be believed:**

- *I'm telling you, he's the best player in the American League.*
- *We’ve been waiting a long time for this, I’ll tell you.*

I would like to know if it would be perfectly natural to use "I'm telling you" in this example:

Person 1: They stole my phone.

Person 2: Come on, they didn't steal your phone. Are you sure you didn't just leave it at home?

Person 1: Yes! I'm telling you, they stole my phone.

?

Comment: Yes, that's reasonable usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is very natural and idiomatic.

Depending on someone’s personality, age, and background, they may also say other phrases (roughly in order of popularity [not exhaustive]) such as: “believe me,” “I swear to God,” “No bull[expletive],” “No cap,” or “No lie” (these last two are slang young people are more likely to use and not really grammatically correct).

Only “believe me” and “I’m telling you” would be appropriate for a formal or workplace setting.